# How to force open "Save as..." dialog on left click for downloading file from remote server

Tags: javascript, download, cross-browser

I want to open "Save as..." dialog on left click on link for file downloading from not my servers. Main idea - create link for downloading image, image getting with bad name. I want to force edit it in browser dialog, before user download it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really can't force a save-as dialog. Sorry.

**Alternative approach**

When they click a link you can use javascript to show a prompt for a better name. When they have filled in the name you can use the html5 `<a download="name">` attribute to provide a link that downloads with the better name.